# d3-shape error when creating line in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to implement the D3 v4 line graph, as per [Mike Bostock's article](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) on it, but am doing this in Angular 2.

I have installed D3 v4 and the required typings. Extract from my `package.json`:

```
"@types/d3": "^4.9.0",
"@types/d3-array": "^1.2.0",
"@types/d3-axis": "^1.0.8",
"@types/d3-scale": "^1.0.6",
"@types/d3-shape": "^1.2.0",
"@types/d3-time-format": "^2.0.5",
...
"d3": "4.9.0",
"d3-array": "^1.2.0",
"d3-axis": "^1.0.8",
"d3-scale": "^1.0.6",
"d3-shape": "^1.2.0",
"d3-time-format": "^2.0.5",
```

However, I am receiving an error when trying to create the `line` variable, as it is expecting a `[number, number]` but as per the guide I need to pass it an item of data here so it can pick up the date and value. My code is:

```
var line = d3Shape.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

The two errors this generates are:

```
Property 'date' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
```

Has anyone else encountered this error, and know how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this before and it was a lot of confusion because of the typings. I was using angular 4.x and was stuck with same problem. The solution was simply to make typescript know about the type and generics came to rescue here:

First declare the type of data for the d3 line:

```
export type LineData = { date: any, value: any };
```

Then use it using the generic method as below:

```
var line = d3Shape.line<LineData>()
    .x(function(d) { return this.x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return this.y(d.value); });
```

Hope that helps!